# Oracle like Pattern-matching LIKE Condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use a column in a like Condition like following 'UPDATE'

```
 UPDATE CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS ct
 SET PROCESSID = vQUARTER 
 where ct.CUSTOMERID = l_arrc1(i).CUSTOMERID 
 and ct.APPOINTOFCAID = l_arrc1(i).APPOINTOFCAID        
 and ct.INVOICEID like "'"||l_arrc1(i).INVOICEID||%||"'";
```

instead

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS ct
SET PROCESSID = '2015Q4'
where ct.CUSTOMERID = l_arrc1(i).CUSTOMERID 
and ct.APPOINTOFCAID = l_arrc1(i).APPOINTOFCAID        
and ct.INVOICEID like '0158741%';
```

the `INVOICEID` and `l_arrc1(i).INVOICEID` are VARCHAR

how to do that?

Comment: Use `%` as placeholders

Comment: Dynamic SQL, maybe..

Comment: an example please

Comment: What is the data type of `INVOICEID` in `l_arrcl`? What is the dtaa type of `INVOICEID` in`CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `INVOICEID` is `number` columns:

```
UPDATE customer_transactions ct
   SET processid = vQUARTER
 WHERE ct.customerid = l_arrc1(i).customerid
   AND ct.appointofcaid = l_arrc1(i).appointofcaid
   AND to_char(ct.invoiceid) LIKE to_char(l_arrc1(i).INVOICEID) || '%';
```

If invoiceid is not `number` datatype then you can remove `to_char`

Comment: the ct.invoiceid and the INVOICEID is VARCHAR type, but I make your change and not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting errors? Post some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing appropriate delimiters for the strings, single quotes:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS ct
    SET PROCESSID = vQUARTER 
    WHERE ct.CUSTOMERID = l_arrc1(i).CUSTOMERID and
          ct.APPOINTOFCAID = l_arrc1(i).APPOINTOFCAID and      
          ct.INVOICEID LIKE l_arrc1(i).INVOICEID || '%' ;
```

The appropriate delimiter for strings in SQL is single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: Gordon Linoff is not working, how to add a single quote before l_arrc1(i).INVOICEID, the ''' is not working

Comment: Why do you need a single quote before the string?  `like` takes a string parameter.  You only need a single quote when the parameter is a constant.